# How to run Java from command line?

Tags: java

I am trying to run java from the command line but having no luck. I have the Java JDK installed in

```
c:\Program files\Java\JDK-20\
```

with java.exe in

```
c:\Program files\Java\JDK-20\Java\bin
```

and have put the above directory in my PATH.
I have also set environment variables

```
  JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\JDK-20  
  JAVA_PATH=c:\Program Files\Java\JDK-20\bin\java.exe
```

If I run "java.exe -version" from the above dir it appears to work OK: I get a dump of java info

```
java version "20" 2023-03-21
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20+36-2344)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+36-2344, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If I try to run that command from any other directory, I get the error

```
Error: missing 'server' JVM at 'c:\dev\bin\server\jvm.dll  
Please install or use the  JRE or JDK that contains these missing components
```

**I'm confused. What am I doing wrong?**

Below is an image of my JDK/bin directory and PATH:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Using `echo %PATH%` and `where java` inside CMD window should tell you enough to work out what is wrong with your PATH setup. Make sure it does not contain oracle javapath or other JRE before your preferred JRE

Comment: Is java on your path? I think you can do something like `set PATH=c:\\Program\ Files\\Java\\JDK-20\\Java\\bin:%PATH%`

Comment: Is c:\dev where you are trying to run your program from?

Comment: * I think you can do something like set PATH=...*c:\\Program\ Files\\Java\\JDK-20\\Java\\bin:%PATH% – 
matt
8 mins ago

Comment: `c:\Program files\Java\JDK-20\Java\bin` Are you sure about that? On my machine, `java.exe` is in this folder: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin`. I suggest that you post a screen capture of your _File Explorer_ showing the location of file `java.exe` See here: https://imgur.com/5M7pcom

Comment: I have posted the requested screen shot to my question,

Comment: I don't know what [environment variable] `JAVA_PATH` is. I don't think Java recognizes that variable. Open a command prompt window and enter the command `echo %PATH%` and see if folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin` appears in the command output. If it doesn't, then you need to add it. How you add it depends on which Windows version you have. Do you have Windows 11? Also, which JDK did you install? Is it Oracle's?

Comment: I have added screen shot of my PATH setting and YES, java.exe is on that path. I am trying to run "java.exe  -version" from different places. Should work, no? I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the PATH variable so the operating system can find the `java.exe` executable.

Comment: Yes, edit Environment variables and **pre**pend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to PATH  There's nothing called JAVA_PATH that I know of

Comment: Prepend or append depends on your configuration and if you really want to put Java before the operating systems and every other applications in the path.

Comment: Prepending removes any possibility that you will get the wrong Java executing. Append will only work if you're *certain* that no other Java exists already. If it did, you'd have to remove it first

Comment: That's my point; depends on the system and what you are trying to do.